# How do I see a value on register?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I read books on assembly language, a chapter about instructions. I understand what is doing the instruction mov, but i don't understand how do I check and see a result. I wrote a hello world.

```
.global _start
.data
some_var:
    .long 0x000721
.text
_start:
mov  $1, %rax         # system call 1 is write
mov  $1, %rdi         # file handle 1 is stdout
#  mov  $message, %rsi  # address of string to output
mov $0x1, %rsi
mov  $2, %rdx # number of bytes
syscall               # invoke operating system to do the write
                    # exit(0)
mov  $60, %rax        # system call 60 is exit
xor  %rdi, %rdi       # we want return code 0
syscall               # invoke operating system to exit
message:
.ascii  "Hello, Universe)\n"
```

But why it doesn't work. How do I see the value at memory and register?

os: linux (debian). intel 64-bit

Comment: it isn't the answer or improvement of it,just a comment. I recommend you learn to use a debugger tool. Even with a `printf()` implementation may be hard(say,inviable) to see values in some cases. Look at `gdb`. Is a very nice tool for some UNIX-like systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an *address* in `rsi`, not a value.
That's why it works with

```
mov  $message, %rsi
```

but not with

```
mov $0x1, %rsi
```

If you want to print numbers, you need a routine to convert numbers into ASCII strings first (basically you need to write a simple version of `printf`).

Comment: If you want to print a number,it's easy.An ASCII-to-integer routine is trivial.But a `printf` implementation take a some time..